# How to count pdf pages in fragment

Tags: java, android, pdf, count, fragment

To count pdf pages in a fragment I use https://github.com/TomRoush/PdfBox-Android but I got an error in line 197.

The error is:

`Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x2`

And my code is:

```
if (requestCode== 86 && resultCode==RESULT_OK && data!=null){
        pdfUri = data.getData();   //return the uri of selected file.
        notification.setText(data.getData().getLastPathSegment());
        try {
            PDFBoxResourceLoader.init(applicationContext);
            PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(applicationContext.getContentResolver().openInputStream(pdfUri));
            noOfPages.setText(doc.getNumberOfPages());            //line 197
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error! " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            getActivity().finish();
        }
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Please select a file",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by fragment? (See the [tag:fragment] tag hover text, fragment is very ambiguous.)

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the text via `setText()` but that has multiple [overloads](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView) , especially these 2 are interesting:

```
final void setText(int resid)
final void setText(CharSequence text)
```

So you are setting the Number of Pages as the text, but the value is an `int` - so the upper overload is used. Now the Number of Pages is not going to match any String constant (aka Resources) - that is basically the error.

You wanted to use the 2nd overload. To to that, pass a `String` instead of `int`.

either by `doc.getNumberOfPages().toString()` or by using `String.valueOf(doc.getNumberOfPages())`.